# UnsuppotedOperationException.getCause returns itself

Tags: java, android, reflection

I have the following Java code in Android

```
Method getIfaceMethod =
            service.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getIface", new Class<?>[0]);
getIfaceMethod.invoke(param1)));
```

Sometimes, an Exception is thrown when it fails to invoke the method via reflection. The thrown exception is UnspportedOperationException. The weird thing is that when I call getCause it returns itself - take a look at the screen shot from the debugger:
[image: Debugger screen shot]

What the hell??

Comment: Is getIface an Interface?

Comment: Nice one... But some more code would help here

Comment: @fge Sorry, I know it's super annoying, but this is a small piece of code I would rather not share. But what we do there is :
1. Call a private method from an class under the Android namespace, invoke that method. This method returns an OS service - that never throws
2. Invoke a method on that service - that sometimes throws the above exception.

BTW - notice that the message is also empty

Comment: @R.Suntjens - no, it is a method returning some strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [sourcecode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Throwable.java#Throwable.0cause) of `Throwable` then you see that the default value of the variable `cause` is `this`, which means that the cause of this exception has not yet been initialized.

If you [further look](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Throwable.java#Throwable.getCause%28%29) at the `getCause()` method of `Throwable`, you see that this should actually be checked and return null, if the `cause` still points at itself. 
**However**, you are inspecting the field(!) `cause` of the exception with the debugger and therefore, this check is not performed.

Comment: Nice! I actually used (by accident) Gson to serialize the exception, instead of passing it e.toString or e.getMessage. And that meant I got an infinite recursion, because it kept trying to serialize the cause, which meant it had to serialize the exception again and again. And Gson probably looks at the fields and obviously not the getters